# How to get all posts of user's groups from Facebook API?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I would like to ask if there is a way, how to get posts from Facebook groups of specific user with `user_groups` permission.
I know I should do it by logging through my Facebook app, but I have to submit a special review in order the app to work with `user_groups` permissions and it takes a time.

Is there any other way how to get that group's posts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you actually checked the [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/)? Please do more research and share what you have found / doesn't work,

Comment: Your app will never be approved for user_groups and there is no other way

Comment: @QualityCatalyst: Yes, of course, but [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/group) in `groups` docs - section **Reading/Permissions** is said that I need any valid access token for access to posts of any public group and `user_groups` permission token to access any groups that the session user is a member of. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @WizKid: Why the app will never be approved for that kind of permission?

Comment: Because https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-user_groups say so

Comment: Thanks @WizKid, finalIy I see what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such way. On April 30th, the first version of Facebook API will be unusable. You need to implement the functionalities for the second version and then complete the review. I have been there, I feel your pain.